# Shared library compiles but has undefined references

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, makefile

I have two projects. Project "vDevice" compiles into "libvDevice.so". This library is then used by the other project "videoViewer", which compiles into a binary "app_videoViewer". These were both working fine before I added a call to `avdevice_reigster_all()` in one of vDevice's files.

vDevice.so compiles and links with no errors. In the makefile I have `-L${FFMPEG_PATH}` (where all the libav*.a files are located), and `-l` avformat, avcodec, avutil, asound, avdevice, and bz2 (in that order).

When I try to make videoViewer now, I get this error:

```
Linking application app_videoViewer ...
/path/to/lib/libvDevice.so: undefined reference to `avdevice_register_all'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

For videoViewer I added the same things to the makefile, linking to avformat, avcodec, avutil, asound, avdevice, and bz2, all before vDevice... what am I missing?

Comment: Missing symbols are searched for in libraries when the `-llibrary` flag is seen. You need the objects *before* the libraries.

Comment: Meaning put -`lvDevice` before `-lavformat`, etc.? For some reason I thought it was supposed to be the other way around.. Switching the order worked though! Would you mind putting this as an answer?

Comment: This is essentially a "duplicate" of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc (and a number of other questions as well).